# Configuração de domínio em tomcat- aplicações jsf

Tags: jsf, tomcat, dns, domínio

Tenho uma aplicação jsf rodando no servidor da empresa, utilizando o Tomcat 8.5.
Atualmente faço apontamento do ip do servidor através do serviço do site noip.com configurado em meu roteador.
Só que recentemente o serviço está falhando.
Gostaria de saber se é possível configurar meu domínio no tomcat sem utilizar provedores.
Tenho um domínio registrado no registro.br.
Como faria este apontamento, uma vez que o ip do provedor de minha internet é dinâmico?É possível isso?

Answer (score 0):

Isto não é um problema específico do Tomcat; é algo na camada TCP/IP. Se seu IP for dinâmico, você vai precisar de algum serviço de DNS dinâmico.

Comment: assim como já uso o no-ip?

Comment: Exato, existem outros serviços de DNS dinâmico;  este site tem uma lista: http://dnslookup.me/dynamic-dns/

Comment: aí com  esse serviço , como eu configuro no meu sistema? Através de virtual host do tomcat?Ou configuro meu domínio dentro do servidor de dns ?

Comment: O virtual host do Tomcat serviria para poder servir múltiplos DNS a partir do mesmo. No seu caso, teria que configurar o servidor de DNS dinâmico.